# Laravel api authentication for admins

Tags: api, authentication, laravel-5, vuejs2

I want to build website which consist of 2 parts: 
1. Pages for ordinary users
2. Admin panel to have ability to change information on the website 
using vue.js (I want to use vue.js only in admin panel)

I've already created auth for admin user (forgot password, change password, login) and it works fine but when I started creating api resource for working with it in admin panel through vue.js I realised that I can't protect api routes using ordinary middleware but I must protect this,
so now it seems I must create brand new auth system and use this for auth on my website but I'm afraid in that case I must use vue.js on "Pages for ordinary users" (I don't want use it there)
I'm a little bit confused how to make it properly

I'm beginner in the area, so sorry guys for silly question
but how can I properly organize auth system on my web site ?

thanks :)

Comment: Why not create two separate website..1 for ordinary users and 1 for admins and point both to the same database?

Comment: is that good way ? 
or may be eventually would be better to make new api auth and use vue.js on both parts ? (part for "ordinary users" has a few pages is that good way to use vue.js on a few pages ? )

Comment: it really depends on the scale of the project, if its going to be a huge project with multiple teams working...its better to have to different code base and two different development teams..if the team size is small like 1-2 developers you can go with the middleware approach

Comment: Thank you Flemin very much !
will see, actually my customer hasn't knew yet how big the project is going to be, now it has no more than 7 pages, but may be in the future he will want me to expand this :)